# Arduino based hour counter

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, ds3231-alarms

I would like to make a hour counter for a particular machine.I have a problem in coding.arduino internal clock can work only till 49 days.my hour counter should calculate 150+ hours.I thought of using a condition to store a particular value and add with next value.How can I code adding values to a variable

Comment: If you make a `millis()` based timer, and use it like the `BlinkWithoutDelay` sketch does, then you shouldn't have a problem. I think the `BlinkWithoutDelay` sketch comes with the Arduino IDE.